# How to make the Newsletter plugin visible to users with author privileges?

Tags: user-roles, newsletter, privileges

I'm using the [Newsletter plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/newsletter/) and would like to make it accessible to author users. Is it possible to do so? If there's no solution for this I'll edit the editor role to make it a new author role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin contains for example these lines:

```
add_menu_page('Newsletter', 'Newsletter', 
              ($this->options['editor'] == 1) ? 'manage_categories' : 'manage_options', 
              'newsletter_main_index');

add_submenu_page('newsletter_main_index', $title, $title, 
              ($newsletter->options['editor'] == 1) ? 'manage_categories' : 'manage_options', 
              $name, $name);


add_submenu_page(null, $title, $title, 
              ($newsletter->options['editor'] == 1) ? 'manage_categories' : 'manage_options', 
              $name, $name);
```

so it looks like you have the option to display the *Newsletter* menu for *editors* (`manage_categories`) or *admins* (`manage_options`).

If this menu is going to be accessible for *authors*, you would need for example the  `publish_post` capability.

Instead of modifying the plugin directly, and loose the modification on each update, you should try to ask the plugin author to add this as an option.

In the meanwhile you could try to add the `manage_categories` capability to the *authors*, if you are happy with that kind of temporary quick fix.